# MBTiles to PostGIS

Tags: postgis, imagery, mbtiles

I have  an MBTiles file /database containing aerial imagery.
Does any one out there know of a way to store a MBtiles database into a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: I can only guess that  what I want is not possible.

Comment: A year later, did you figure out anything?

Comment: Just ask chatGPT!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know I do not think this is possible. If someone knows of a way then please let me know I have many uses for such a tool!

A MBtiles database is essentially a bunch of SQLite files compiled from PostGIS data. I.e. Some source -> PostGIS data -> MBtiles. There are a couple of options you have here:

1. Feed PostGIS data to a tile server (PostGIS -> HTTP server ex: dirt -> tile server -> tiles)
2. Host the precompiled MBtiles file on a server somewhere (ex: AWS s3) and then serve directly from the MBtiles file.

I use route 2 personally I have found it a lot simpler to configure than option 1.